# Is it possible to limit the size of text-type field in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, size, fieldtype

I know that it can be done with `varchar`, `char` and others. but, is it possible with `text`?

Comment: You use `text` when your data is dynamic and you don't know how long it is. So setting a length for it doesn't make sense.

Comment: it does, to me. i need it to be between 0 and 2,300 characters. utf8 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TEXT itself can't be limited, but you can limit - through the code that's handling then passing it to the PHP - how much the user can enter.  For example, in javascript, if "str.length>X" you could alert "Stop being so long-winded," rather than posting to the PHP handling page - that is, of course, very easily defeated.  However, couple that with a check in the php before putting it into the database, and you should be good.